# How to merge decision/fork nodes in UML

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I have the below UML activity diagram for a shopping cart use case. It has several decision and fork nodes but there are no corresponding join/merge nodes. Could you please show me:

- how to correct the diagram by introducing the merge/join nodes.
- how to modify the diagram so that a customer can repeat the process (of adding more products to the shopping cart).

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an initial activity element anywhere?  Makes it a bit easier to read.  To your question, the merge should be used as opposed to having multiple connectors coming into the same activity.  For instance, "Acknowledge Msg" should have a merge above it that the other branches can flow into.

As for how to make it repeatable, you may want an "Add to Cart" action, and prior to a "Checkout" action, have a Decision with guards for "Shopping Complete" (which goes to the Checkout action) and "Continue Shopping" (which goes back to "Enter Product #").

Comment: Is it a merge (bar) or join (diamond) above 'Acknowledge msg'?  The flows from ErrMsg 1 & ErrMsg 2 are alternates, not parallel.  A merge would wait on both before progressing - which would never happen.  It's a while since I looked at activity diagram semantics though, so you may be right...

Comment: Apologies - I got terminology the wrong way round.  Diamond is called Merge node so you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the **token concept**. It is introduced in petri nets and also used in the UML activity diagram.

**Decision nodes** produce one token only, i.e. they follow just one outgoing path. To merge such paths, of which only was is followed, you can use a **merge node**. Which just looks like a reversed decision node and is able to consume exactly one token. A diamond with multiple incoming edges.

If you use a **parallelization node** to start concurrent execution paths, you have multiple tokens leaving the parallelization node. To merge these kind of paths, you can use a **synchronization node**, it looks like a reversed parallelization node and has to consume one token per incoming edge.

[image: Both, decision and merge, and pararellization and synchronization nodes]
<sub>(source: [amg at www.lcc.uma.es](http://www.lcc.uma.es/~amg/ISE/OOP-Java-UML/Chapter%204_archivos/4-ActivityUML.gif))</sub>